# Managing per form ObjectContext lifetime

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, orm

For ORMs like EF and NHibernate, [multiple](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices/) [places](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx) suggest using "context per method" (or per request, per transaction) for web apps and services and using "context per form" for thick clients like WinForms and WPF. In C#, resource disposal with context per method is clean and clear with a `using` block.

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) { /* ... */ }
```

However, using WinForms, there are a few possible places to call `context.Dispose()`: FormClosing event, FormClosed event, Finalizer, OnClosing override, OnClosed override, do nothing and let GC collect it.

What is the best way to dispose of "context per form" resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As strange as it sounds ,you don't have to dispose you DbContext (IF you haven't manually opened the connection yourself)
Have a look at this:
      [Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects? Nope](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

That said , I suggest that you use one context per method(and dispose it)  and not per form ,especially if you have long lived forms.

With long lived you might have problems with outdated data every now and then,plus context construction is not an expensive process.
    Now if you still want a context per form I don't think there a much difference in which event you will call it